# What does כסיה mean?

Tags: words, beshalach, text, maseches-pesachim

The [Gemara in Pesachim 117a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.117a) brings a disagreement whether כס יה, in the [last pasuk of Beshalach](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.17.16), is one word or two.  As far as I know all modern Sifrei Torah (Ashkenazi, Sefardi, Teimoni) have two words, but according to [מאורות נתן](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33644&st=&pgnum=8&hilite=), the Keter has כסיה as a single word.

What does כסיה mean?  Is it still "the Throne of Hashem" or does it mean something different?

Comment: Do any of the combinations in Pesachim mean anything other than what they would mean as two words?

Comment: The missing Aleph, if formed into a single word, could be understood to mean the concealment of the name, Aleph, Yud, Heh which I believe is part of the name formed from 72 triplets, meaning the 216 letter name pronounced by the Kohen Gadol on Yom Kippur.

Comment: @Heshy I've never actually seen it in a Torah, but there were Rishonim and Acharonim who would intentionally write כס hung above יה to be yotzei the safek since you can hang half a word. See Tashbetz 1:177 and Ginat Veradim 2:4 (thought you'd enjoy)

Answer (score 5):

Rav Dovid Tzvi Hoffman on this Passuk suggests that the word כסיה would mean forever/ongoing:

> ואולי הפירוש של ״כסיה״ – לדעתם של אלה הסוברים כי תיבה אחת יש כאן – הוא: המכוסה, העטוף, כלומר הנצח, כמו ״עולם״ מלשון עלם, להסתיר, ופירושו של הכתוב הוא אפוא: יהא זאת מצבת נצח

Rabbi Chaim Heller (footnote 11 [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37702&st=&pgnum=30)) suggests that it would mean "throne", just as כסא does.